# Generate Unique Random number in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm loading data from Flat file to SQL Server database. Along with the normal column, i want to add one more column with unique random number. I have around `500000` rows as of now. I have created a Derived column and added the expression

```
ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))
```

to that. But it is throwing error `NEWID was not recognised`. I understand this is not supported in SSIS. Please help me here. Is there any other function that i can use for this? I searched some of the stackoverflow question but it didn't helped.

Comment: SSIS doesn't use SQL, it uses it's own expression language; you can't expect SQL to work as an SSIS expression. Why not not insert a value to that column and set the above expression to the columns `DEFAULT` value?

Comment: Ok. Actualy i'm trying to load error records to Error table. Here when the record(same combination) is repeating 4 times. First record inserted into normal table. second record is getting inserted into error table. Again now when same record comes,it is throwing Primary Key violation error in the error table. Hence I want to generate some unique combination for duplicates as error table contains PK as PK of normal table + unique number column. @Larnu

Comment: This all feels like information that sould be in your question. This feels like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.com)

Comment: Do you truly need a random number or will a sequential one work? If random is needed, I _presume_ it also needs to be unique?

Comment: Why don't you just remove the PK on the error table? Do you truly expect to only ever get a single error per ID?

Comment: Just use an identity column as your PK on your error table.

Comment: As suggested, I solved it by creating a DEFAULT value in the table. Thanks all for your valuable comments.